# Co-routine tail spinning

Tags: python

Could I connect two coroutines A and B that A would excite B and B would excite A? For example, A would accept a number, print it and invoke B with (number+1). B would print it and invoke A with (number+1). I would expect 1,2,3,4,5,... printed

This code unfortunately does work as intended

```
def coroutine(func):
    def start(*args,**kwargs):
        cr = func(*args,**kwargs)
        cr.next()
        return cr
    return start

_target_from_a = None
_target_from_b = None

@coroutine
def func_a():
    while True:
        item = yield
        print 'a', item
        _target_from_a.send(item + 1)

@coroutine
def func_b():
    while True:
        item = yield
        print 'b', item
        _target_from_b.send(item + 1)

a = func_a()
b = func_b()
_target_from_a = b
_target_from_b = a

a.send(1)
```

it produces the followng [error](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/):

```
a 1
b 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "coloop.py", line 31, in <module>
    a.send(1)
  File "coloop.py", line 17, in func_a
    _target_from_a.send(item + 1)
  File "coloop.py", line 24, in func_b
    _target_from_b.send(item + 1)
ValueError: generator already executing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `_target_from_a.send(something)` the `a` coroutine, **before being "paused" by the `yield`** calls `b` which resumes execution and what it does is:

```
    item = yield
    print 'b', item
    _target_from_b.send(item + 1)   # ARGH!!
```

The problem is that `_target_from_b.send(item + 1)` will try to call `a`. But `a` in this instant is not waiting for anything, it is still executing.

Keep in mind that a coroutine is just like any other function when it executes. Calling `_target_from_a.send()` does *not* pause the coroutine, but python simply executes the function call.

Summary: **Never** make loops with coroutines. They simply cannot work.

Note that the `generator already executing` exception may also be raised when accessing the same generator/coroutine from multiple threads.

---

I'll suggest you to read ["A Curious Course on Coroutines and Concurrency"](http://dabeaz.com/coroutines/) By David Beazley, who explains really well how coroutines should be used and how they work.